# ls-remote reports phantom tags ending with "^{}"

Tags: git

What are the tags that end with '^{}'?  They don't actually exist in the bare repository.

```
$ git ls-remote -t origin
55f09717db93733b8f151763e7e28628f3f22129        refs/tags/Init
dce13158fff0e95b8adcc5628f193a8c03bada9c        refs/tags/Init^{}
2c9f64c306aa76e5b689bc2ffb41163aa255ac40        refs/tags/kaos-red
0970feca84d87df60ec5e943da2f55f1947fd0a3        refs/tags/legacy
dce13158fff0e95b8adcc5628f193a8c03bada9c        refs/tags/legacy^{}
```

When I try to delete them with "git push :legacy^{}" for example, git responds

```
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :Init^{}
```

So where are they coming from?  Is it a bug in ls-remote?

Comment: Dupe of [What does ^{} mean in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938972/what-does-mean-in-git)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [git rev-parse manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) describes the various ways you can specify commits or other objects in git. For this case it says:

> ^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{}
>   A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to bulk delete tags in my remote git repository, in some result documents I found from Google, I found the command like

```
git ls-remote --tag | awk '/(.*)(\s+)(.*)/ {print ":" $2}' | xargs git push origin
```

or something like that. (the same problem it will show phantom tags ending with ^{})

If you want to do the same thing like me, you can try to use the git command show-ref

```
git show-ref --tag | awk '/(.*)(\s+)(.*)/ {print ":" $2}' | xargs git push origin
```

In the latter way, you will not be blocked by this problem.