# Adding ssh key to gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I installed Gitlab on a Fedora 17 server following [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos) guide and I believe everything works fine, except that I cannot add ssh keys or push my local repository to the server.

When trying to add a SSH key via the web interface I get the message "Fingerprint cannot be generated"

When I try to push the local repo to the server with

```
    git remote add origin git@myserver:user/repo.git
    git push -u origin master
```

It asks me for the password of the git user, which I cannot introduce since it does not have one. How can I fix this? I've tried to search the logs for debugging information but could not find anything.

edit: I've tried adding my public rsa key to authorized_keys and I can ssh without entering the password (the session closes because login is disabled for this user). However, when I try to push origin master I get the following

```
    fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This
```

Comment: Found the solution to the git push problem in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314298/git-push-results-in-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-this

Comment: https://jxqc.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/gitlab-key-is-invalid-fingerprint-cannot-be-generated/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the `"Fingerprint cannot be generated"`: GitLab needs access to /tmp for generating fingerprints, and SELinux might be preventing that. [Relevant Discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5027#issuecomment-24585540)

Comment: I executed those commands and it works now. Thanks! Now I only need to get the regular git push to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OpenSSH version of key.

Under *Linux you can get this version of key with command:
ssh-keygen -i -f /tmp/id_rsa.pub >>

Under Windows you can use Pyttygen application:
open your key, then menu Conversions -> export OpenSSH key.

I guess it helps you :)