# Unable to push to local git repo

Tags: git

I am  trying to create a git repo on localhost. I followed the following tutorial: https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-locally/
Everything works fine until I try to make the first push. I get the following error:

> fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: JAVA

Many questions similar to this, suggests that I should look for echo statements in .bashrc file. But there are no echo statements there.  I get the same error when I try to push to a remote repo as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that this can happen due to  of problems with the Shell access (is the access allowed?) on the server..

Perhaps this link would be of any help: [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436). It seems related.

Comment: I do have shell access, however not sure if I have to explicitly pass on the authentication info also?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash git
```

Also, the following post might provide more information on this: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314298/git-push-results-in-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-this)

Reason (Quoted from post):

> The reason for changing the login shell is because the default shell
>   for the git user is /sbin/nologin (or similar, depending on
>   environment), which prevents the git application from logging in as
>   the git user on the git server.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a few time when run through TeamCity. In our case the /tmp space is full, clearing it removes the problem.

Unfortunately I can't explain why this causes the problem.