# Error: protocol error: bad line length character: erro

Tags: github, git-bash

Tried to push to my GitHub URL and it gives me this weird error. I don't see anyone else having this error.  I can pull from my git directory but not push.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314298/git-push-results-in-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-this or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab ?

Comment: Expressing your hope for help should never be part of your question. No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour))

Answer (score 0):

It's known, that there can be different reasons for such a problem (some answers are already linked), but in our case its text was just the same, and it was caused by lack of RAM:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Erro
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```