# GitLab-omnibus 7.9 on Banana Pi error when pushing to directory on external hard drive

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-7

I'm using a Banana Pi 1 with Ubuntu 14.04.5 Trusty Tahr (32bit architecture). I like to use the Banana Pi as my privat GitLab Server. I successfully installed gitlab-omnibus 7.9. See system information below:

```
System information
System:
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.1.5p273
Gem Version:    2.2.1
Bundler Version:1.5.3
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:3.3.0

GitLab information
Version:        7.9.0
Revision:       16d6f0e
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     postgresql
URL:            http://192.168.0.115
HTTP Clone URL: http://192.168.0.115/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@192.168.0.115:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        2.6.0
Repositories:   /media/Seagate Expansion Dr/Projekte/GitLab/git-data/repositories
Hooks:          /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

Commiting and pushing works fine over ssh but at the moment the git data is stored ad the SD card of the Banana Pi (where ubuntu is installed as well). I hooked up an external hard drive and I can access this drive as well when I log in via ssh. Now I want gitlab to store the git data on this external hard drive (name: Seagate Expansion Dr). I followed the guide in the
[gitlab README.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#changing-the-name-of-th$). So did the following:

1. I synchronized the repositorie on the banana pi in the default location
   `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/` to the new location `/media/Seagate\ Expansion\ Dr/Projekte/GitLab/git-data` (for a more detailed description see 
   [gitlab README.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#changing-the-name-of-th$))
2. I added the following line to /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

   ```
   git_data_dir "/media/Seagate\ Expansion\ Dr/Projekte/GitLab/git-data"
   ```
3. reconfigured and restarted gitlab

   ```
   gitlab-ctl reconfigure
   gitlab-ctl restart
   ```

But now when I try to push something from my repositorie on my Windows Desktop PC to the Banana Pi via:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: No s
```

I did some research and think the error has something to do with permissions so I gave owner, group and others permission on write, reade and execute for a test but the error remains.

I would be very happy if somebody can help me. If any further information are needed ask me right away.

Best regards,
Bredjo :)

Comment: Try to remove the spaces of the directory path. It is generally never a good idea to add those in a path, as it will likely lead to problems later on.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @secustor. I renamed my HDD and while doing that I had an idea that the mounting is maybe not correct so I [mounted](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/mount/) the hdd (name is now SeagateExpansion) fresh and I also made an entry in the /etc/fstab regarding. But the problem remains so I thought maybe the user _git_ has not enough right so I also created a new group _GitLabUser_ and signed the user _git_ and my personal user in and after that I set the mount option of the hdd for the group id to `gid=GitLabUser`. But the error remains.

Comment: check the Gitlab logs under `/var/log/gitlab/`and see following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab

Comment: I looked at the logs and the most interesting ones are empty. I also tried a few things from the thread you send me but until now without success. But I have still a few things I want to try. At the moment I'm pushing my documents to the SD card of the Banana Pi. Thank you so far for you help I think the solution is somewhere in the link you send me.  I get back with an update when I made some progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works :) :) :)

1. the error I experienced when pushing means `No such project` (source: [Git push results in fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314298/git-push-results-in-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-this)). So GitLab doesn't know or find the project.
2. My log files weren't actually empty I haven't looked properly (see comments above). @secustor thank you for the hint with the logs. The error in `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log` says the following:

   ```
   W, [2017-07-30T19:20:41.433749 #21264]  WARN -- : gitlab-shell: Access denied for git command <git-receive-pack 'Richard/Survival_Indie_Development.git'> by user with key key-6.
   ```

During my research I found this forum entry which describes the same problem I have: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730. I found this link early but at that point of time I struggled with other problems.

To solve the problem I had to edit the gitlab-shell config file: `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml`. I filled in the Banana PI IP-address and the port to the following lines: `gitlab_url: "192.168.0.115:80"` and `host: 192.168.0.115`. After this I executed:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

and

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

et voilà it works :). For testing i deleted the previous repos in the default gitlab directory and it still works. Now my git data gets stored on the external HDD :).

Comment: Small update: After restarting and reconfiguring gitlab I noticed that my changes in `config.yml` were replaced by the default values ... strange. But everything is still working.

Comment: that is normal behaviour. If you use `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, Gitlab will update all configuration files with the values supplied in the `gitlab.rb` file. To prevent this overwritting of the YAML files, simply change the values there.