# Is it possible to get branch names without clone or pull from git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to get all branch names of a git repository. Currently, I clone the repository then get them on local machine. This is inefficient because all I need is names and nothing else.

I wonder if it is possible to do that? If so, what command I can use.

Comment: As long as you have access to the remote repository in question you can take a look in the `refs/heads` folder which you can find in your remote repository. The files in there are effectively the branches of the repository.

Comment: @Zeeker This requires shell access which is almost always disabled for git users.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Locally, without cloning, you can type (using git [`ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)):

```
git ls-remote /url/of/the/upstream/repo
```

That will list of the remote HEADS and their associated branches

Comment: Why does that command return two tags `refs/tags/TAG` and `refs/tags/TAG^{}` despite the fact that I only have one?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938972/what-does-mean-in-git. Thank you for your help!