# Git merge one branch to another between only two tags

Tags: git

I need to merge from one branch to another but only between selected tags in Git

your help highly appreciates.

Comment: A branch is not a chain of commits; it is the name of one commit. Do you mean you want to cherry pick the tagged commit?

Comment: @matt thank you for your reply, In my scenario, I am maintaining a different branch to different version so I need to merge selected commits from the master branch. To identify the selected commits I have added two tags from start commit to ending commit. as per my understanding cherry-pick can only merge only selected commits not the set of commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as per my understanding cherry-pick can only merge only selected commits not the set of commits

[`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) can apply a *set* of commits, as I describe in "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)"

In your case:

```
git cherry-pick tag1^{}..tag2^{}
```

`{}^` is the [dereference notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12939216/6309).
Make sure that `tag1` reference the oldest commit.
And understand this will not move the tags, which will still reference their original commits.