# When listing git-ls-remote why there's "^{}" after the tag name?

Tags: git

When I run `git ls-remote` in the work tree, the command outputs a list of revisions in the origin repo. For some reason I get 2 revisions with every tag and for the second revision of the same tag, the tag name includes `^{}`

```
git ls-remote
From git@github.com:andris9/zzzzzz.git
d69e66d7c915b9682618b7f304b80cc0ae4c7809    HEAD
....
bb944682f7f65272137de74ed18605e49257356c    refs/tags/v0.1.6
771a930dc0ba86769d6862bc4dc100acc50170fa    refs/tags/v0.1.6^{}
a72251d945353a360087eb78ee75287c38a1c0e6    refs/tags/v0.1.7
d69e66d7c915b9682618b7f304b80cc0ae4c7809    refs/tags/v0.1.7^{}
```

I create tags with

```
git tag -a v0.1.8 -m "tag message"
git push --tags
```

From the examples of `git-ls-remote` [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) there are no such duplicate tags, so maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think it is correct that this question has been closed as duplicate, as the question asks _specifically_ about `^{}` in the context of git-ls-remote. In that context, the answer has important difference in comparison to more generic responses (for instance there is not option to `--dereference` in git-ls-remote. Hence I vote to re-open this question!

Answer (score 184, accepted):

There are 2 types of tags:

- **lightweight** - merely refs that point to some object (like a commit).
- **annotated** - a separate git object by themselves, and store a lot more information like author, committer, a commit message, etc.

When you used `git tag -a` to create a tag, git would have created an annotated tag for you.

The `^{}` is the syntax used to dereference a tag. It is described in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions).

- When used with tag objects, git would recursively dereference the tag until it finds a non-tag object.
- When used with non-tag objects, it doesn't do anything and is equivalent to skipping the `^{}`

The `refs/tags/v0.1.6` ref in your repository points to the tag object `bb944682f7f65272137de74ed18605e49257356c`, which in turn points to `771a930dc0ba86769d6862bc4dc100acc50170fa` (a non-tag object) which I'm guesssing is storing the commit information when you created the tag.

So when you do `refs/tags/v0.1.6^{}`, git is going to dereference the tag and resolve it to `771a930dc0ba86769d6862bc4dc100acc50170fa` - the non-tag object.

There is also a [`git show-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-ref.html) command that can be used to list only tags, and optionally dereference as follows, and in your case should produce the following output:

```
$ git show-ref --tags
bb944682f7f65272137de74ed18605e49257356c    refs/tags/v0.1.6
a72251d945353a360087eb78ee75287c38a1c0e6    refs/tags/v0.1.7

$ git show-ref --tags --dereference
bb944682f7f65272137de74ed18605e49257356c    refs/tags/v0.1.6
771a930dc0ba86769d6862bc4dc100acc50170fa    refs/tags/v0.1.6^{}
a72251d945353a360087eb78ee75287c38a1c0e6    refs/tags/v0.1.7
d69e66d7c915b9682618b7f304b80cc0ae4c7809    refs/tags/v0.1.7^{}
```

To confirm this, you can use [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) command to give you more details about the git object.

This is the information from one of my test git repositories.

```
$ git show 43f9a98886ba873c0468c608f24c408b9991414f
tag v0.1
Tagger: Ash <tuxdude@OptimusPrime>
Date:   Sun Jul 15 00:14:43 2012 -0700

Tagging Stable repo 0.1 :)
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
<PGP-SIGNATURE>
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

commit e55df25f2321a6b2c9a02fa80ccba7cbe3c38c08
Merge: 796efcd 58e3a4d
Author: Ash <tuxdude@OptimusPrime>
Date:   Sun Jul 15 00:02:44 2012 -0700

    Merge branch 'dev' into 'master' for stable 0.1.

$ git show e55df25f2321a6b2c9a02fa80ccba7cbe3c38c08
commit e55df25f2321a6b2c9a02fa80ccba7cbe3c38c08
Merge: 796efcd 58e3a4d
Author: Ash <tuxdude@OptimusPrime>
Date:   Sun Jul 15 00:02:44 2012 -0700

    Merge branch 'dev' into 'master' for stable 0.1.
```

Comment: This explanation is better than the one given in the duplicated question!