# Duplicated tag on remote?

Tags: git, git-tag

I made two local tags, `1.0.0.1308` and `1.0.1.1308`:

```
$ git show-ref
2cc0513083619934459832c175b433ee1ecfedf9 refs/heads/master
2cc0513083619934459832c175b433ee1ecfedf9 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
2cc0513083619934459832c175b433ee1ecfedf9 refs/remotes/origin/master
8ba818dae2fd892b44df64e4a5ee9e07d4e682fb refs/tags/1.0.0.1308
dc4ea0fb4899ea6fffc47e203923a980c0de7d98 refs/tags/1.0.1.1308
```

When I `git push --tags` I got on the remote:

```
$ git ls-remote
2cc0513083619934459832c175b433ee1ecfedf9        HEAD
2cc0513083619934459832c175b433ee1ecfedf9        refs/heads/master
8ba818dae2fd892b44df64e4a5ee9e07d4e682fb        refs/tags/1.0.0.1308
6df34f6333097b77d8d6bb907155807b1e1cb19b        refs/tags/1.0.0.1308^{}
dc4ea0fb4899ea6fffc47e203923a980c0de7d98        refs/tags/1.0.1.1308
2cc0513083619934459832c175b433ee1ecfedf9        refs/tags/1.0.1.1308^{}
```

Why it created `1.0.0.1308^{}` and `1.0.1.1308^{}`?

---

P.S.: I just tried deleting the tag on the remote (`git push origin :tagname`), it also deletes the one with `^{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tagname^{}` syntax means "the object to which the tag points". See [man git-rev-parse](http://jk.gs/git-rev-parse.html).

Annotated tags consist of a tag object (which contains the tag message, and other data), which references another object (the thing which was actually tagged). The line `refs/tags/1.0.1.1308` says that the *tag object* has the id `dc4ea0f`.

The `refs/tags/1.0.1.1308^{}` line then tells whoever wants to know that the tag `1.0.1.1308` points to the object `2cc0513`, which is probably a commit (although things other than commits can be tagged).

That is, when you tagged the object `2cc0513`, you created a tag with id `dc4ea0f`.

Comment: There's a more in-depth explanation in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472107/when-listing-git-ls-remote-why-theres-after-the-tag-name/15472310#15472310. I was confused about why _some_ tags in my repo showed a `^{}` duplicate and some didn't, and it was helpful in explaining that (short answer: it varies depending on whether the tag is annotated, e.g. with a message, or not).