# Git branch/tag name with ^{}

Tags: git

Running the command `git ls-remote` lists the following entries:

```
e6c1ddea6ee8eefa9e96e349dd4fad4a48c16448    refs/tags/1.1
1a3b5ae3a50ca2f24e5cd917cbf51d371f1dd01e    refs/tags/1.1^{}
81901877c5add523cd4a4bb8f51ad3bbbacbd686    refs/tags/1.2
4681b1ae6ec71301019da13d1790c2f808c2c553    refs/tags/1.2^{}
```

What does the `^{}` mean in the output?

Comment: http://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html - A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

Comment: See the answers to these questions:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938972/what-does-mean-in-git
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472107/when-listing-git-ls-remote-why-theres-after-the-tag-name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicated tag on remote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510642/duplicated-tag-on-remote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not part of the name, but rather an indicator to [git rev-parse](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) that it should dereference a tag (and, with any luck, find a commit, although in theory the tag could point to another tag, or even a tree or blob; but if it points to another tag, the `^{}` keeps on peeling the onion layers until it hits a non-tag).

`git ls-remote` (or really, the remote itself) uses this syntax to send you the commit-ID.  (I'm not quite sure what happens if the tag ultimately points to a tree or blob.)

Comment: Do you know why git has both the 1.x and the 1.x^{} items?

Comment: Because it's an annotated tag, so `refs/tags/1.1` (or more precisely, `e6c1dde...`) is the tag object.  The remote wants (rather helpfully) to get you the commit ID, so you can tell if you have the commit already.