# bitbake git fetcher failure

Tags: git, bitbake, yocto

I have a custom kernel recipe in Yocto Project's poky. I was using it with dylan-9.0.0 (1.4.0 distro) version and it worked fine.

EDIT: the new version I'm using currently: daisy with 1.6.1 distro version.

Now I changed to daisy and the git fetcher fails to find the tag.

Log:

> DEBUG: Python function base_do_fetch finished | DEBUG: Python function
>   do_fetch finished | ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL:
>   'git://git.myserver.com/custom-linux;protocol=git;tag=1.8'. The
>   command git ls-remote git://git.myserver.com/custom-linux
>   refs/heads/1.8 refs/tags/1.8^{} gave empty output unexpectedly ERROR:
>   Task 70 (/opt/poky/meta-mine/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-custom_1.8.bb,
>   do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

`git ls-remote git://git.myserver.com/custom-linux refs/heads/1.8 refs/tags/1.8^{}`
 really gives empty output called from command line, but if I do `git ls-remote git://git.myserver.com/custom-linux refs/heads/1.8 refs/tags/1.8` 
then it returns the tag I'm looking for.

So... the problem is **^{}** at the end of the URL. I guess it worked in a different way with previous versions.

Do you have any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472107/when-listing-git-ls-remote-why-theres-after-the-tag-name

Comment: Well... yes, it's relevant, but it's not really an answer to my problem. It clarifies what's that ^{}, but I still don't know why it isn't enough if I have a simple 1.8 tag.

Comment: I could solve it this way: I removed tag=1.8 from SRC_URI and defined SRCREV variable with the commit identifier hash in my recipe, and I had to append branch=mybranch to the end of SRC_URI variable. This way it works perfectly, but I wouldn't say it's a nice solution.

Comment: @Attila_Horvath Great! You should post this as an answer, so others will see this as solved.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I ended up using for this was to make sure all tags we created and intended to fetch via yocto were annotated tags.  When you create a non-annotated tag it doesn't add the deferenced pointer in refs/tags/ (i.e. the ^{} version) and because the yocto fetcher is looking for that dereferenced version it fails.  When you create an annotated tag, it will automatically create that version for you and it will be found.