# how to know whether a tag is local or remote?

Tags: git, tags

1.I have many tags in my project, How can I know whether the tag is local or remote easily and clearly?(`ls-remote` is useful but hardly diff)

2.I run `git ls-remote --tags origin` it prints

```
abcde  refs/tags/aaaa
abcee  refs/tags/aaaa^{}
```

What does the second line mean?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How you choose to list the tags should make it clear where they are.

`git ls-remote --tags origin` obviously lists remote tags on origin.

`git tag` lists tags locally.

2. See **[What does ^{} mean in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938972/what-does-mean-in-git)** and **[When listing git-ls-remote why there's "^{}" after the tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472107/when-listing-git-ls-remote-why-theres-after-the-tag-name/15472310#15472310)**.