# List all tags that contain a specific commit on remote server?

Tags: git

This question asked how to do this on local repo: [How to list all tags that contain a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit)

I wonder if there is a way to do this on remote server without fetching tags to local repo. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see remote tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984310/how-to-see-remote-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-remote --tags repo_url
```

You can also find a detailed explanation here, duplicate: [How to see remote tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984310/how-to-see-remote-tags)

Comment: Sorry I realize maybe my question is not very clear. I'm looking for a command to list all tags that contain a (specific) commit on remote server.