# How do I search the content of tag annotations in git?

Tags: git, version-control, tags, full-text-search, release-management

I am about to release the first version of my first git-managed project and am going to tag it with an annotated tag ("first alpha release").  Later on, to find out which was the first alpha release, I would like to search the contents of the tag annotations for "first alpha".  How do I do so?

I know `git log --grep` will search the contents of commit messages and `git show` will tell me the contents of a tag annotation, but I can't figure out from the manpages or Google what command will do a search over tag annotations.  Do I have to dump the records where the tag annotations are stored and search using another tool?  I am envisioning `git show $(git tag)|grep "first alpha"` and hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does use external `grep` but seems to be more elegant than parsing the output of git show:

`git tag -l -n | grep "first alpha"`

and you will get very nicely the output:
`test_1.2.3      first alpha`

*Note the -n flag, here I assume your annotation are one line long. For longer messages you will need to give a number after -n (lets say -n99) and will be more complicated regarding the grep flags. 
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html*

One way to search multiline annotations is with `gawk` (example `bash` command line shown):

```
git tag -l -n99 | gawk -v pat='<some regex>' -- '/^\S/ {tag=$1} $0~pat { print tag }'
```

`/^\S/ {tag=$1}` saves each tag name in turn, and `$0~pat { print tag }'` prints the tag name when a match is found.

Comment: Hidden in plain sight!  Thank you --- I had overlooked the `-n` option.  I see from testing that multiline annotations are indented, which makes it easier to process them.  I will take the liberty of editing your answer to include the `gawk` oneliner I wrote just now to complete the solution.

Comment: A convenient shell script now on [GitHub](https://github.com/cxw42/git-tools/blob/master/git-grep-tag-annotations).

Answer (score 3):

You need `git show` on the [dereferenced tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472310/6309) for exploring the content of the annotated tag "`first alpha release`":

```
git show $(git show-ref -d -s --tags "first tag release"|tail -1| awk '{print $1}')
```

That being said, a git show directly with the tag would give the same result, except for the tag metadata displayed first.

```
git show $(git tag|grep "first alpha")
```

That would show the content of all tags whose tag name includes "first alpha".

Comment: Thank you for the tip on `git show-ref` --- I hadn't used it before.  Upvote!  This answer appears to work well for tag names, but not for the content of the tag annotations (unless I'm missing something), since [patterns are matched in the ref names](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref).  The dereference goes all the way to the tagged commit, so the `$(...)` gives commit hashes rather than tag-object hashes.  I appreciate your time on this answer!