# Bash: cutting a delimited fragment of each string

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file containing lines that look like this:

```
GTTCAGAGTTCTACAGTCCGACGATCGGATGAGNNNNNN
GTTCAGAGTTCTACAGTCCGACGATCTCCGAGTNNNNNN
GTTCAGAGTTCTACAGTCCGACGATCCTTATATNNNNNN
GTTCAGAGTTCTACAGTCCGACGATCGAAGTGCNNNNNN
GTTCAGAGTTCTACAGTCCGACGATCAAGTTTTNNNNNN
GTTCAGAGTTCTACAGTCCGACGATCCGACGAANNNNNN
```

I want to remove the first 26 and final 6 characters from each line. I haven't been able to write a good regular expression to accomplish that using vi, but I'm not sure what else to do.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Great question, it forces to think not linearly on regex

Comment: Regex is not suitable for all problems. It's a heavy hammer for a small problem like grabbing a static set of bytes from a list of strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What linux shell command returns a part of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219402/what-linux-shell-command-returns-a-part-of-a-string), or *why would you use regex when you know exactly how many characters you want to cut?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with grep.

This will keep the last 13 characters and then the first 7, returning only the matching characters (-o) with the Perl-compliant -P flag:

```
grep -oP ".{13}$" foo.txt | grep -oP ".{7}"
```

Comment: don't forget to mark it the correct one when you can, Forest.

Comment: His example lines are 39 characters. What if some were 50 characters? Given known conditions  `unknown length = 26 + unknown segment + 6` Thats 1 equation, 2 unknowns. Yet you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

If your file name is `foo` you can use cut to grab out the range of chars you want:

```
$ cut -c27-33 foo
```

This produces:

```
GGATGAG
TCCGAGT
CTTATAT
GAAGTGC
AAGTTTT
CGACGAA
```

Answer (score 1):

`cut` can take a character range, if the lines are a fixed size (they appear to each be 39 characters)

```
cut -c27-33 file.txt
```